# Is there any software or registry hack to add a specific item to the context menu for specific executables?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, icons, context-menu

Is there any software or registry hack to add a specific item to the context menu for specific executables or associated file types to those executables?

For example, right clicking a.ext would have an option to open it in notepad.
That in itself isn't that useful, since opening the file alone could do that. But it'd be good if more options were available in the context menu, like opening b.ext c.ext.

Comment: You could make use of the SendTo menu http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270

Comment: do you think that'd work for opening a file in an/the application? I am not trying to move or copy anything.

Comment: note- cawas suggested there may be a way to associate the context menu or an item in it, with ..perhaps not an icon or application, but with a file extension/type. since 7-zip has the open archive option in the context menu when right clicking a zip but not for say a txt.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom context menu entry to the filetype based on its extension. Here is an example for *.exe :

- Open [Regedit](http://www.microsoft.com/library/errorpages/smarterror.aspx?aspxerrorpath=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fresources%2Fdocumentation%2Fwindows%2Fxp%2Fall%2Fproddocs%2Fen-us%2Ftools_regeditors.mspx)
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe`
- Make sure that the key called `(Default)` exists and its value is `exefile`
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell`
- Create key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\YourCustomCommand`
- Create key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\YourCustomCommand\command`
- Add new string value named `(Default)` and set it to `"%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1"`
- Close Regedit

Now all executables (*.exe) should have new context menu item called `YourCustomCommand` which will open the file in notepad.